# What paired test should I use and how do I interpret it?

Tags: normal-distribution, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, paired-data

The question:
The data file contains observations of the wavelengths (in nanometers) of 
the main color in two kinds of  shoe polish. (Sample size = 100). Are the wavelengths significantly different?

Now, I figured out I should use a two sided paired sample test. That would mean either Wilcox or a t-test. How do I figure out whether I can use the T-test, or should stick to a nonparametric test like the Wilcoxon signed ranks test? Should I test for a normal distribution?
On a side note: how do I interpret the results of such tests? If the p-value is high, does that mean they are significantly different or the other way round?

Comment: From your description, it's not clear to me why you want to use a paired samples test, it sounds like you should be using an independent samples test.

Comment: Assuming your data are actually paired (are they?), the two tests you list are not the only possibilities. Low p-values suggest a difference.

Comment: Does your hypothesis relate directly to a mean or just some general sense of a location difference? Would you assume the shapes are the same apart from location, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see why this should be a `paired t-test`. There is no connection between the 100 pairs. Paired would be if you have 100 shoes and each shoe is tested with a different laser...ok, that's not a good example ;):

```
shoe | laser 1 | laser 2 | Delta
1      34 nm     38 nm      4 nm
2      33 nm     29 nm     -4 nm
...
```

But maybe I do not understand your description and it is a `paired setting`. But I am afraid that you have to clearify it in this case.

Can you specify what difference in `nm` (wavelength unit) is considered *big enough*? Using `R` you could use:

```
polish.1 = c(25,24,36,24,32)
polish.2 = c(22,36,27,28,30)
BigDifference = 2
t.test(
  polish.1,
  polish.2,
  alternative = "two.sided",
  paired = FALSE,
  mu = BigDifference
  )
```

Leading to:

```
    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  polish.1 and polish.2 
t = -0.7171, df = 7.951, p-value = 0.4938
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 2 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -8.125667  7.325667 
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
     28.2      28.6
```

`Welch` means that it is **not** assumed that the standard deviation of the two data sets is equal.

So the result in the example means that it is not likeley that the wavelength is different (`p-value` is about 50 %).

Of course, we can go deeper in the subject of effect size and so on. But I want to wait what you and the others reply/comment.